# Timeout supported Multithreaded Web Request

Tags: c#, multithreading, webclient

If you are using it for simple purposes, WebClient is enough. Absence of Timeout you can inherit it and override it's GetWebRequest method easily:

```
protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
{
    WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
    request.Timeout = Timeout;
    return request;
}
```

If you are using it multithreaded way, you have to set MaxConnection by code or app.config:  [Improving performance of multithreaded HttpWebRequests in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388908/improving-performance-of-multithreaded-httpwebrequests-in-net)

You can parallelize it easily also:
[Best practics for parallelize web crawler in .net 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688359/best-practics-for-parallelize-web-crawler-in-net-4-0)

Maybe Microsoft created new HttpClient class  for implemantation problems of WebClient (HttpWebRequest)

But it does not have Proxy,Gzip support.

For WebClient:

Setting up Timeout still useless in multithreaded implemantation!

[Concurrency Limit on HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382374/concurrency-limit-on-httpwebrequest)

So the question:

I need FastWebClient with proxy,timeout(working one),gzip support. I will use it with multiple proxies, so I definetely need multiple FastWebClient.

Or Helper:

FastWebHelper.DownloadString (string url,WebProxy proxy,int timeout)

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. [WebClient.DownloadStringAsync Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringasync.aspx)
You would still need to create 1 WebClient instance per connection/request, as it's not stateless.