# Why I can not get Timeout on HttpWebRequest? (HttpWebRequest Timeout nightmare)

Tags: httpwebrequest, timeout

I'm using it in Quartz.Net framework. Every Job(thread) has only one web request

Here is the check list:

- All disposable objects are used in using block!

  ```
  using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
          using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
          using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
              str = reader.ReadToEnd();
  ```
- ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
- ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000;
- ServicePointManager.MaxServicePoints = 1000;
- request.KeepAlive=false
- request.Timeout = 5000;
- request.ReadWriteTimeout = 5000;
- request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 5000;
- request.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 5000;

I'm using Stopwatch to measure web request time. These are that logs:

Abnormal Web Request time: 16333 ms

Abnormal Web Request time: 8350 ms

Abnormal Web Request time: 9846 ms

Abnormal Web Request time: 7545 ms

Abnormal Web Request time: 6662 ms

Abnormal Web Request time: 18332 ms

**Any Idea?**

PS: This question is summarized version of [Timeout supported Multithreaded Web Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353334/timeout-supported-multithreaded-web-request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only lesson that I learned from this problem: If you are using HttpWebRequest in multiple threads don't use it synchronous!